# Is there a performance difference in combining two similar for loops into one?

Tags: c#, performance

Consider the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   stringBuilderObject.Append(something[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   differentStringBuilderObject.Append(somethingElse[i]);
}
```

My question is - would combining them suffice any performance gains, or the complexity is close to the same? (*These are simple examples to demonstrate the question, obviously in real situations the for loops would bear similar functions but with a lot of added context.*)

Combined result:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   stringBuilderObject.Append(something[i]);
   differentStringBuilderObject.Append(somethingElse[i]);
}
```

Comment: Every CPU cycle saved is gain in performance. The second code snipped looped only once instead of 2 for first code snippet

Comment: According to the example in the OP, yes there is a performance gain as you are iterating only once in the combined result. Can't say that for your real world scenarios until you post some examples you are having.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683882/one-loop-with-two-actions-vs-two-loops-with-one-action-performance

Comment: Has been discussed by Eric Lippert here: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) (spoiler: why don't you try and tell us?)

Comment: @user1672994 No, it´s not that simple. In fact the total sum of cpu-instructions is identincal for both versions. So in first code you have 2 * 10 instructions, on second version you have 1 * 20 instructions. In theory we could have some caching as well - which doesn´t apply in OPs example, though.

Comment: @HimBromBeere what would you say is the faster code for the given test case above?

Comment: Why ask us? Just make a benchmark-test (i.e. by making some millions of iterations, not just 10), and see which performs better.

Comment: How often do these loops get used - if you only have 2 loops of 10 iterations used relatively infrequently - then you may be wasting time trying to optimise.

Comment: @PaulF they're being used all the time, I'll be doing some benchmarks as HimBromBeere suggested in the meantime

Comment: Filling a `StringBuilder`, using it, disposing it, and then filling a second `StringBuilder`, seems to me more memory-efficient than filling two `StringBuilder`'s concurrently.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias disposing it? StringBuilder is a managed resource, what do you mean?

Comment: You are right, it is not disposable. I mean to [Clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.clear) it, to release the allocated memory.